# Force DjangoMongoDBEngine not to save Null Fields

Tags: django, mongodb

Suppose we have defined following model:

```
class product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100) # allow null = True
```

In our `product` model, `desc` field can have `Null` value.
As far as MongoDB is a schema-free DB, how can we modify
`product` model not to save `desc` field when its value is `Null`?
(By default, Django will create both `name` and `desc` field with
`desc` field value set to `Null`]

Comment: If the `desc` field has the value null when you go to save, that is the value you are asking to be saved so I think it's right that `null` is put into the document in the database. To stop this, you should just unset `null` from fields before you save it, perhaps with `del`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of [DjangoMongoDBEngine](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/) I used [mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/) and it does that automatically.